# Show selection of child div when text contents are selected

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I have div block inside a content editable. I like to show that the block is selected too when the text is selected along with block. Could not find a way around. any help is appreciated.

I dont want users to select part of the text inside the `embed-block`.

```css
[contenteditable="true"] {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 20px;
}
[contenteditable="true"] > span {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
    
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  lorem ipsum
  <span class="embed-block" draggable="true" data-value="test">
      &#xFEFF;
      <span contenteditable="false">
         <div class="embed-block-child1">
           <div class="embed-block-child2">
              <div class="embed-block-child3">
                 <span style="margin-right:4px">some block</span>
              </div>
           </div>
         </div>
      </span>
      &#xFEFF;
  </span>

  .....
  Following properties effects. user-select, draggble="true"
</div>
```

Result: [image: Result]

Expectation: [image: Expectation]

Comment: Why are you using user-select none when you want to select it?? And if you don't want to select it, then why you want that when user select the other text, it also get selected??

Comment: _"I dont want users to select part of the text inside the embed-block."_ - that is not happening to begin with, due to `draggable="true"` - I can not select text inside this element by itself, every time I try, it gets dragged instead. (At least in a Chromium-based test browser; in Firefox I do not even see the span formatting. Likely due to the fact that you posted SCSS/SASS and not CSS. Which surprisingly Chrome appears to interpret though(?).)

Comment: I have edited your snippet so that it uses real CSS now.  I am a little confused on why you want the text to appear selected even though you have specific code to prevent this from happening.  Why not just remove the `user-select` and allow to to be selectable?

Comment: So my requirement is to show the selection something like in the screenshot. 
And I do not want users to select the part of the text inside the block. Either they select whole text or nothing.

And the selection is if I select it along with other text like in the screenshot. If you drag the block itself, there is a different behavior.

Comment: @FiniteLooper oops. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible unless you just changed the BG color of that element dynamically, but that color is something set on the system level which the browser doesn't have access to.